# Removing last words in each row in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

A dataframe contains a column named 'full_name' and the rows look like this:

```
full_name 
Peter Eli Smith 
Vanessa Mary Ellen 
Raul Gonzales 
Kristine S Lee
```

How do I remove the last words and add an additional column called 'first_middle_name' which will result like this?:

```
full_name          first_middle_name
Peter Eli Smith    Peter Eli 
Vanessa Mary Ellen Vanessa Mary 
Raul Gonzales      Raul 
Kristine S Lee     Kristine S
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can try using `str.replace` here:

```
df["first_middle_name"] = df["full_name"].replace("\s+\S+$", "")
```

See the above regex replacement working in the demo link below.

### Demo

Answer (score 1):

Use `str`

```
df["first_middle_name"] = df["full_name"].str.replace("\s+\S+$", "")
```