# Last word delete but keep if it is only one

Tags: python, pandas

I have a series of texts that has either one word or a combination of words.  I need to delete the last word  its greater than 1, if not leave the last word.

Have tried the following regex:

```
 df["first_middle_name"] = df["full_name"].replace("\s+\S+$", "")
```

from this solution:  [Removing last words in each row in pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63212643/removing-last-words-in-each-row-in-pandas-dataframe)

It deletes certain words keeps others.

Some examples of strings in my df['Municipio']:

```
Zacapa    
San Luis, **Jalapa**    
Antigua Guatemala **Sacatepéquez**    
Guatemala    
Mixco    
Sacapulas, **Jutiapa**    
Puerto Barrios, **Izabal**    
Petén **Petén**    
San Martin Jil, **Chimaltenango**
```

What I need for example is if it finds one word keeps that word, if it is a combination of more words (2 or more) and there is a comma or space delete the last word.  See bold words.

Thank you!

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Comment: why do you delete Jutiapa and not delete Izabal?

Comment: My mistake, it needs to be deleted as well.

Comment: Tried the above regex, join and r.split methods

Answer (score 0):

You can `apply` a function to check if `,` in string first, then check space in string.

```py
df['Municipio'] = df['Municipio'].apply(lambda x: ', '.join(x.split(',')[:-1]) if ',' in x
                                        else (' '.join(x.split(' ')[:-1]) if ' ' in x else x))
```

```
print(df)

           Municipio
0             Zacapa
1           San Luis
2  Antigua Guatemala
3          Guatemala
4              Mixco
5          Sacapulas
6     Puerto Barrios
7              Petén
8     San Martin Jil
```

If you want to keep the last comma and space

```py
df['Municipio'] = df['Municipio'].apply(lambda x: ', '.join(x.split(',')[:-1]+['']) if ',' in x
                                        else (' '.join(x.split(' ')[:-1]+['']) if ' ' in x else x))
```

```
print(df)

            Municipio
0              Zacapa
1          San Luis,
2  Antigua Guatemala
3           Guatemala
4               Mixco
5         Sacapulas,
6    Puerto Barrios,
7              Petén
8    San Martin Jil,
```